# Neural networks numerical labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, fill

The code given below generates a MWE.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{neuralnetwork}

\newcommand{\linklab}[4]{\ifnum0=#2 $w_{0}$ \else $w_{{#2}}$ \fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{neuralnetwork} 

\inputlayer[count=3, bias=true]
\outputlayer[count=1, bias=false]\linklayers[style={above,sloped},labels=\linklab]

\end{neuralnetwork}
\end{document}
```

[image]

TO (generated by inkscape)

[image]

I would like to use numerical labels **automatically**. The code should give (for example) `1.5, 2.3, 1` and `5.1` instead of `w_0, w_1, w_2` and `w_3` when I write `\label = {1.5, 2.3, 1, 5.1}` (or sth. similar).

I tried to use `foreach` with `ifnum` but could not get what I would like.

Comment: I believe that the success of any approach with your `\linklab` macro requires knowledge, how `\outputlayer` treats the `labels=` argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{neuralnetwork}
\newcommand{\linklab}[4]{\ifcase#2
0
\or
1.5
\or
2.3
\or
1
\or
5.1
\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{neuralnetwork} 

\inputlayer[count=3, bias=true]
\outputlayer[count=1, bias=false]\linklayers[style={above,sloped},labels=\linklab]

\end{neuralnetwork}
\end{document}
```

[image]